# Joining two csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I want to join two csv files into one like this:

```
**file 1:**
feb,55,1.23,..,..,0
mar,65,2.33,..,..,1

**file 2:**
feb,55,..,12,KL,..
mar,65,..,10,MN,..
```

so the output would be something like this:

```
feb,55,1.23,12,KL,0
mar,65,2.33,10,MN,1
```

My following code snippet doesn't works:

```
f1=[li.split(',') for li in open("file1.csv","r+")]
f2=[lj.split('\t') for lj in open("file2.csv","r+")]

def joinL(x,y):
    list=[]
    for n in x:
        for m in y:
            if n[0]==m[0]:
                list.append(m)
    return list

print joinL(f1,f2)
```

Could you please help
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265831/merging-2-csv-files

Comment: If I understand correctly in one case you have "1.23" and in the other "2" and "33" in the same spot after fussion and I assume that is not know when this happens. Is there are chance that "2","33" is actually "2.33"

Comment: Yeaaah, I am sorryyy, it s 2.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
with open('filename1', 'r') as fl1:
    f1 = [i.split(',') for i in fl1.read().split('\n')]

with open('filename2', 'r') as fl2:
    f2 = [i.split(',') for i in fl2.read().split('\n')]

f3 = [[a if b is None or b==len(b)*b[0] else b for a,b in map(None,x,y)] for x,y in zip(f1,f2)]

for i in f3:
    for j in i:
        print j,
    print

[OUTPUT]
feb,55,1.23,12,KL,0
mar,65,2.33,10,MN,1
```

Note, you had a minor mistake in your text. It should be `2.33` not `2,33`.

Here is ***EXACTLY*** the code I am using:

```
#my_script.py
with open('t1.txt', 'r') as fl1:
    f1 = [i.split(',') for i in fl1.read().split('\n')]

with open('t2.txt', 'r') as fl2:
    f2 = [i.split(',') for i in fl2.read().split('\n')]

f3 = [[a if b is None or b==len(b)*b[0] else b for a,b in map(None,x,y)] for x,y in zip(f1,f2)]

for i in f3:
    for j in i:
        print j,
    print
```

---

```
#t1.txt
feb,55,1.23,..,..,0
mar,65,2.33,..,..,1
```

---

```
#t2.txt
feb,55,..,12,KL,..
mar,65,..,10,MN,..
```

Comment: Is it a mistake is still a question :-)

Comment: it gaves me
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Doublexo, It works fine for me. Are you sure you didn't change any of the code?

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote:

with open('log1.csv', 'r') as fl1:

    f1 = [i.split(',') for i in fl1.read().split('\n')]


with open('log2.csv', 'r') as fl2:
    f2 = [i.split(',') for i in fl2.read().split('\n')]


j=[[a if b is None or b==len(b)*b[0] else b for a,b in map(None,x,y)] for x,y in zip(f1,f2)]


for k in j:
 for l in k:
  print l
 print

Comment: @Doublexo, Did you make note of the error you had in your text file, I have shown in my answer. Also, did you replace, the two filenames above with your appropriate filenames?

Comment: and here is the error:
j=[[a if b is None or b==len(b)*b[0] else b for a,b in map(None,x,y)] for x,y in zip(f1,f2)]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: yeaah I did exactly what you said
and my files are log1.csv and log2.csv

Comment: Could you please explain to me what does b==len(b)*b[0] mean??
THANKS