# Combining two csv files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

Can anyone check for me what's wrong with my code. 
I want it merge two csv file into one csv file.

**I hve tried to google and I still cant merge it, it will create new file but will show nothing inside.**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16266144/7624469

> **a.csv**

```
ID    User
A1    Fi
A2    Ki
```

> **b.csv**

```
ID    User
A4    Fsdi
A5    Kisd
```

> The output that I want will look like this
>
> **combined.csv**

```
ID    User
A1    Fi
A2    Ki
A4    Fsdi
A5    Kisd
```

**test.py**

```
import pandas, sys
import pandas as pd


a = pd.read_csv("C:/JIRA Excel File/a.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("C:/JIRA Excel File/b.csv")

merged = a.merge(b, on='ID')

merged.to_csv('C:/JIRA Excel File/result.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using `df.append`:

```
out = df1.append(df2)
print(out)

   ID  User
0  A1    Fi
1  A2    Ki
0  A4  Fsdi
1  A5  Kisd

with open('C:/JIRA Excel File/result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    out.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

Answer (score 12):

It is better to use `pd.concat` here to combine this frames, not `merge`:

```
merged = pd.concat([a,b])
```

Toy example with your data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([['Fi'],['Ki']],columns=['User'], index=['A1','A2'],) #'ID')
b = pd.DataFrame([['Fi'],['Ki']],columns=['User'], index=['A4','A5'],) #'ID')
pd.concat([a,b])
```

Will output:

```
    User
A1  Fi
A2  Ki
A4  Fi
A5  Ki
```

Comment: it will display this error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 53: invalid start byte

Comment: The unicode error has nothing to do with your original question. Specify the correct encoding to [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: What's the practical difference between your suggestion of `concat` vs `append` as suggested in the accepted answer?

Comment: `append` is depreciated.