# Combining two csv files into another csv file without affecting previous data in the output csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Hello, I have google searched everything but I still can't find something that fits my needs.**

I found this: [Combining two csv files using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069709/combining-two-csv-files-using-pandas)

But it's not doing what I want.

> **Code**

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("b.csv")

out = df1.append(df2)

with open('main.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    out.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

> **a.csv**

```
col1    col2    col3
a        b        c
d        e        f
```

> **b.csv**

```
col1    col2    col3
g        h        i
j        k        l
```

> **main.csv**
> It seems to output nicely...

```
col1    col2    col3
a        b        c
d        e        f
g        h        i
j        k        l
```

> However, when I try to remove data in **a.csv** or in **b.csv**, it seems to remove that specific data in **main.csv**
>
> Example:
> **a.csv** (Removed a,b,c)

```
col1    col2    col3
d        e        f
```

> **b.csv**

```
col1    col2    col3
g        h        i
j        k        l
```

> **main.csv**

```
col1    col2    col3

d        e        f
g        h        i
j        k        l
```

It seems to leave a gap and removes the data if I remove some data in either csv. Basically, **a.csv** and **b.csv** is always changing and I want to combine these two without altering the original data that the **main.csv** have. I would also like that **main.csv** don't get duplicate rows.

Comment: how are you removing `a,b,c`?

Comment: I experimented and I manually remove those rows in excel. It seems that when I remove something and append the two csv files and output it into the third csv file, It removes that data and just leaves a gap.

Comment: You need to code a merge function that will merge two csv files. Then you will first merge main.csv with a.csv followed by merge with b.csv. To code merge, you can read from csv to a List of tuples and then when you read from the second file, you can check for existence in the list. That will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the file in append mode instead of write mode , Below will be the correct way

```
with open('main.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     out.to_csv(f, index=False)
```

for removing duplicated, refer the below question

[Removing duplicate rows from a csv file using a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741564/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-csv-file-using-a-python-script)