# How do find the sum of difference between two csv

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files.

```
Csv 1
A 1
B 2
C 3

Csv 2
A 10
B 20
C 30
```

How do i find the sum difference of column 2

Like 10-1+20-2+30-3

So output csv would be

```
A 9
B 18
C 27

Total 54
```

I can achieve the difference but not total. Any help?

Comment: You should show what code you have.

Comment: I trying sir but it is not allowing me to edit. Using phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the inbuild `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open("Csv 1.csv") as csvfile_1, open("Csv 2.csv") as csvfile_2, open('outfile.csv', "w", newline="") as outfile_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile_1, delimiter=" ")     #read file 1
    reader2 = csv.reader(csvfile_2, delimiter=" ")    #read file 2
    writer = csv.writer(outfile_csv, delimiter=" ")   #Create writer object
    c = 0
    for m, n in zip(reader2, reader):
        val = int(m[1])-int(n[1])
        writer.writerow([m[0], int(m[1])-int(n[1])])  #Write result.
        c += val
    writer.writerow(["Total", c])  #Write Total
```

Comment: But how can i achieve total at the end. ?

Comment: @James. Did not see the last bit. Updated snippet

Answer (score 1):

Time to get familiar with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, columns=['name', 'value'])
sum = data['value'].sum()
```

Pandas has heaps of well-documented functions that you can use to determine differences between columns/rows.

Or, for your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'value'])
for file in filepaths:
    new_df = pd.read_csv(file, columns=['name', 'value'])
    pd.append(df, new_df)
sum = data['value'].sum()
```

But this is quite basic and loses some information regarding where the original data came from, in which case you want to start thinking about how to properly [construct your dataframe with indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069709/combining-two-csv-files-using-pandas)

Comment: You are only achieving the second part of the question an not addressing adding to csv or the differences. also `data` in your second code is incorrect. and what is that link you are pointing to supposed to help with?

Answer (score 0):

first read your csv using pandas(you have to use your fileName/ path instead of file1.csv, file2.csv):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',header=None)
```

then find difference into another dataframe:

```
df3 = df2
df3[1] = df2[1].sub(df1[1], axis = 0)
```

then write your final datafarame into csv:

```
df3.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

you can find sum:

```
print(df3[1].sum())
```

output:
54

```
print(df3)
```

output:

```
    0   1
0   A   9
1   B   18
2   C   27
```