# how to merge multiple CSV files into one file and create super schema in final CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-2.x, python-2.4

how to merge multiple CSV files into one CSV file in the python 2.4 version(python 2.x). I want to merge almost 30 CSV files into a single CSV file. The final CSV file contains super schema columns(all columns from each file). non-available column values consider for empty value or blank space value in the final CSV file.

first file:

```
file111.csv:
"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","EXEC_TIME","DBT_TIME","CALLOUT_TIME","CLIENT_IP"
"BBCout","20191011000022.423","95","0","2019-01-11T00:00:05.300Z","200.50.000.333" 
"BBCout","20200403122024.123","96","1","2020-04-03T00:00:05.300Z","300.50.000.333"
"BBCout","20210102083426.543","92","0","2021-01-02T00:00:05.300Z","400.50.000.333"
```

second file:

```
file222.csv:
"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","TYPE","METHOD","TIME","RT_SIZE","URL","UID_DERIVED","CLIENT_IP"
"AACallout","20210215000030.815","REST","POST","61","71","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055QAQ","200.50.000.333"
"AACallout","20201210000012.800","REST","GET","67","75","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055BBBQ","300.00.000.111"
```

final merged CSV should contain all columns and non-available columns should be empty values or blank space.

final CSV file.

```
result.csv

"E_TYPE","TIMESTAMP","CLIENT_IP","EXEC_TIME","DBT_TIME","CALLOUT_TIME","TYPE","METHOD","TIME","RT_SIZE","URL","UID_DERIVED"
"BBCout","20191011000022.423","200.50.000.333","95","0","2019-01-11T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"BBCout","20200403122024.123","300.50.000.333","96","1","2020-04-03T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"BBCout","20210102083426.543","400.50.000.333","92","0","2021-01-02T00:00:05.300Z",,,,,,
"AACallout","20210215000030.815","200.50.000.333",,,,"REST","POST","61","71","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055QAQ"
"AACallout","20201210000012.800","300.00.000.111",,,,"REST","GET","67","75","""https://st.aaa.xxx.net/n1/yyy/zzz""","0055BBBQ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.append` to achieve just that!

[Combining two csv files using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46070094/15294091)

[pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)