# Python Compare Datasets

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv files.

One that has columns that look like this:

```
10.10.10.10 madeupdnsentry.domain.com
```

and the other looks like this:

```
10.10.10.10 ABCD.EFGH.1234
```

I'd like to compare and combine the entries that match. So I could end up with:

```
10.10.10.10 madeupdnsentry.domain.com ABCD.EFGH.1234
```

What would be the best way to do that? It has about 1000 entries some will have matches some won't. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging 2 csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265831/merging-2-csv-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas`. Note that this is essentially doing an `inner join` so if there are unmatched records between the two data sets they will fall out. But you can change the join using the `how` keyword argument in the `merge` function.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data1 = [['10.10.10.10','madeupdnsentry.domain.com']] 
>>> data2 = [['10.10.10.10','ABCD.EFGH.1234']]
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['ip', 'domain1'])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['ip', 'domain2'])
>>> df1.merge(df2, on='ip')
            ip                    domain1         domain2
0  10.10.10.10  madeupdnsentry.domain.com  ABCD.EFGH.1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read in the csv files with Pandas using `pandas.read_csv(path)`, and then use the .merge() function in pandas to join them on whichever column you would like, and can set how the join is done by passing the parameter `how`, for example `df1.merge(df2, on='some_column', how='left')`